# UPDATE source table upon succesfull INSERT into target table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to udpate source table (cut out a string from a field) upon a succesful insert into a target table. I found some examples of similar tasks, but not exactly this. I am looking for something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ConditionsAsignments]
       ([ConditionID]
       ,[SRCtableID])
SELECT
        8 as ConditionID   
       ,SRC.ID as SRCtableID   
FROM SRCtable as SRC 
WHERE SRC.BusinessConditionText LIKE '%Prices are ex VAT.%'

OUTPUT INSERTED.*
UPDATE SRC.BusinessConditionText = SUBSTRING(...cut out the searched text...) 
WHERE SRC.ID = SRCtableID
```

Performance is not an issue, this is only a data migration script.

Comment: is your like predicate fixed or it may vary?

Comment: `OUTPUT` in a temp table, then `UPDATE` from that temp table and put the `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` in the same `TRANSACTION` and you should be fine.

Comment: LIKE string will be fixed, though I will repeat it few times with different strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Adwaenyth, as I followed his comment.

I took a wild guess and it seems to work as desired:

```
CREATE TABLE #IDins(ID INT)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ConditionsAsignments]
       ([ConditionID]
       ,[SRCtableID])
OUTPUT INSERTED.SRCtableID INTO #IDins   -- outputing to a TEMP table
SELECT
        8 as ConditionID   
       ,SRC.ID as SRCtableID   
FROM SRCtable as SRC 
WHERE SRC.BusinessConditionText LIKE '%Prices are ex VAT.%'

UPDATE SRCtable SET BusinessConditionText = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(...cut out the searched text...)) 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #IDins)     -- modifiying only lines, which have inserts

GO

-- can be repeated with a different string ---
```

Answer (score -1):

use "After Insert Trigger" for your target table.

Comment: Well, I think triggers are to be used for permanent tasks, not for operative data processing? It would be possible to use triggers though, but I was hoping to learn a straight-forward, simple way I could easily use in future in similar cases...

Comment: please let me know your straight-forward, simple way !! @Oak_3260548

Comment: Well, the idea was to find out, if there is any :-). And perhaps the triggers wouldn't be that complicated, but I don't know them much, so they would be for me. But anyways, the temp table solution proposed by Adwaenyth is a feasible solution and it's not complicated, so I will remember it.